# Is the phrase "... or I'm mistaken" correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, question-tags

I want to write phrase "Capital of A is B, or I'm mistaken?", but I'm not sure that the second part of thus phrase is correct. Should I write "... or I've made a mistake?", or "... or I'm wrong?"? What is the best?

Comment: "The capital of A is B, or am I mistaken?"

Comment: No reason to downvote this question from a non-native speaker of English. ELL isn't in beta yet. When will it be in beta?

Comment: Thank you, Bill. I was interested what is the ELL, but found the answer: It is "English Language Learners" new site than is discussed to be created in the stack exchange universe. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the question stands, the OP asks if (forms of) ***mistake*** can be used as other than a noun (*Should I write "... or I've made a mistake?"*).

In that sense, the "Capital of A is B, or I'm mistaken?" **is correct** in the use of *mistaken* as an adjective.

> **[mis·tak·en](https://www.google.com/search?q=mistaken&tbs=dfn:1)** /məˈstākən/
>   *Adjective*
>    1. Wrong in one's opinion or judgment.
>    2. (esp. of a belief) Based on or resulting from a misunderstanding or
>       faulty judgment: "an unfortunate case of mistaken identity".

Incidentally, minor errors of grammar need correction:
"***The*** capital of A is B, or **am I** mistaken?"
is how you would write the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

What you’re looking for is “...if I’m not mistaken,” but it's rather a cliché. “...if I remember correctly” is not much better. “...I believe” is a bit more honest.

Expressing a little doubt in these clichéd expressions actually indicates certainty: you *know* you’re not mistaken, and it’s a false modesty.

Comment: Actually, I think he’s looking for “. . . unless I’m mistaken.”